# Limiting behavior of the associated Laguerre polynomial

Tags: special-functions, laguerre-polynomials

From [How to show orthogonality of associated Laguerre polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2350219/how-to-show-orthogonality-of-associated-laguerre-polynomials) or [Finding a generating function for the Laguerre polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92612/finding-a-generating-function-for-the-laguerre-polynomials) it appears that the expression, $L^q_p(x)$ is that of an associated Laguerre polynomial and defined as

$$
L^q_p(x)=\frac{x^{−q}\exp{(x)}}{p!}\frac{d^p}{dx^p}\left(x^{(p+q)}\exp{(−x)}\right). 
$$

However I am not quite sure what the $q$th order derivative means, for a non-integer $q$.

I am looking for the limiting behaviour of $L_q^p(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$, or as $x\rightarrow0$. I am most interested in the cases that $p$ is a half integer (that is, $p=\frac m2$ and $q=\pm\frac12$. I found some help (for my special cases) at
[Associated Laguerre polynomials of half-integer parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187779/associated-laguerre-polynomials-of-half-integer-parameters) but the answer says it is just an empirical formula with unestablished formal validity.

Any suggestions/help on how to proceed? Just a reference or two, or some suggested step would be extremely helpful, and much apprecited.